# Module "vue" has no exported member 'configureCompat' Vue3

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vuejs3, migration

I am currently migrating an application from Vue2 to Vue3.
Following the official guide, Migration Build | Vue 3 Migration Guide (vuejs.org), I am trying to maintain compatibility with Vue2 by using the 'configureCompat' setting, which supports compatibility between Vue2 and Vue3.
However, an error occurs at `import { configureCompat } from "vue";`.
Could you advise me on how to resolve this error?
The error message is: **Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'configureCompat'.**


I believe there is no issue with the versions of 'vue' and 'vue/compat'. I tried deleting 'node_module' and reinstalling it with 'npm install', but the error still occurs.
Here is the relevant portion of main.ts:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import vuetify from "./vuetify";
 
import { configureCompat } from "vue";
import { defineRule, configure } from "vee-validate";
import { required, email, min, max, length, digits } from "@vee-validate/rules";
import { localize } from "@vee-validate/i18n";
import ja from "@vee-validate/i18n/dist/locale/ja.json";
 
const app = createApp(App);
 
configureCompat({
  FEATURE_ID_A: false,
  FEATURE_ID_B: false,
});
```

package.json

```
pacakge.json
  "dependencies": {
    "@vee-validate/i18n": "^4.11.8",
    "@vee-validate/rules": "^4.11.8",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13",
    "vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^9.1.2",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.3",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0",
    "yup": "^1.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/compat": "^3.3.4",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "typescript": "~4.5.5",
    "vee-validate": "^4.11.8",
    "vuetify": "^3.3.20"
  },
```

Comment: I see you're using TypeScript. Have you followed step 4 of the [migration guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/migration-build.html#upgrade-workflow)? It says: `If you are using TypeScript, you will also need to modify vue's typing to expose the default export`

Comment: Thank you comment!!
oh...you're right.
I did step 4 of the migration guide then probrem was resoleved.

Thank you so much.